# SSH: prevent from asking for passphrase when ssh-agent auth fails

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent, passphrase

I am writing a script to cycle through a list a known hostnames so as to find a working SSH server on which I can auth with my SSH key.

The key is **already loaded** with `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add`, so if I connect to a working remote host that knows my key, no passphrase is prompted and I am successfully connected without any interaction.

Thing is, when the remote host does not know my key, `ssh` prompts me with the passphrase (it has no chance to succeed because, if it could, it would have already logged me in thanks to `ssh-agent`). I would like to prevent this behavior and make `ssh` abort when the `ssh-agent` auth fails.

I am currently using the following command to bypass most of the interaction but I can not prevent the one I just described:

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa                      \
      -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null       \
      -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no    \
      -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no           \
      -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey \
      -o ConnectTimeout=1                   \
      $host -n "whoami"
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

man ssh_config:

```
 BatchMode
         If set to ``yes'', passphrase/password querying will be disabled.
         This option is useful in scripts and other batch jobs where no
         user is present to supply the password.  The argument must be
         ``yes'' or ``no''.  The default is ``no''.
```

Comment: Indeed, it did the trick. I did not notice this option in SSH manapage, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While the BatchMode answer is certainly the right one, I want to also mention that you can also do: -o PasswordAuthentication=no ; same man page.